# JavaScript issue on WordPress website

Tags: wordpress

may I know why all JS not loading in this WordPress site? How to solve this issue?

https://www.znameseveky.cz/

Comment: we do not know. yet. missing a bunch of codes to look at

Answer (score 0):

There could be a syntax error in either functions.php or footer.php, as the page gets cut off after `</main>`.